# Selecting a random list and then pulling information from that list

Tags: python, list, random

I know how to append and access random data from a list. I'm trying to randomize one of the Lists (A, B, or C), then use data from those lists.

Is it as simple as changing random_list to match the actual List_A (or b/c)? Or am I going about it all wrong?

```
import random

All_Lists = ["List_A", "List_B", "List_C"]
List_A = ["Albert", "Apple", "3", "Alpaca", "4"]
List_B = ["Barbara", "Banana", "6", "Baboon", "3"]
List_C = ["Calvin", "Carrot", "1", "Cat", "0"]

rand_idy = int(random.random() * len(All_Lists))
random_list = All_Lists[rand_idy]
print(random_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `All_Lists` as follows, and move it to after the other lists:

```
All_Lists = [List_A, List_B, List_C]
```

Note the lack of quotation marks.

In general, you don't reference Python variables by strings that name them. See also: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-I-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess it was easy.